# Why will this not execute the code to give a success message?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form for updating data including name , email and age I click the update user button and i will get the error please fill in the required fields.

I have tried writing the sql statement may ways including checking the table name.

```
{
<?php

$sql = "UPDATE u_data SET Email = '$Email' , Name = ''$Name' , Age = '$Age' WHERE Id = '$Id'";      
if(mysqli_query($conn , $sql))
{
    if(!empty($Email) || !empty($Name) || !empty($Age))
    {
        $Success = "User has been Updated Successfully!";
        header("Location: Updating_U.php?Success=" . urlencode($Success));
        exit();
    }   
}
?>
}
```

When i fill out all form fields a message is supposed to say User has been Updated Successfully!. But instead i always get an error saying please fill in the required fields. I have no idea why the database  row won't update with new data.

Comment: There is no code to output required fields error, is this coming directly from mysql?

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET["Success"])) { ?>
        <div class="w3-center w3-green">
         <?php
          echo $_GET["Success"];
         ?>
        </div>
       <?php } ?> There is this code What do you mean directly from mysqli? I have this code on the same page.

Comment: It is likely that your code is not outputting a success string because your database has some null validation for some columns. Also, your code is **HIGHLY** vulnerable to php injection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I know i have spent some time trying to get this to work? I will check the database for null values

Comment: Please include the exact text of error messages in these kinds of reports.

Comment: You should check whether the variables are empty before doing the `UPDATE`. And you should use `&&` to combine the tests, not `||`.

Comment: if(empty($Email) || $Email == '' || empty($Name) || $Name == '' || empty($Age) || $Age == '')
     {
      $Required = "Please fill in the required fields";
       header("Location: Updating_I.php?Required=" . urlencode($Required));
      exit(); 
     } This  code come before else

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code is **Highly** vulnerable to PHP injection. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

You also had a typo in your SQL query string.

```
<?php
//You had a typo in this line! An extra quote
$sql = "UPDATE u_data SET Email = '$Email' , Name = '$Name' , Age = '$Age' WHERE Id = '$Id'";      

if(!empty($Email) || !empty($Name) || !empty($Age)) {
    if(mysqli_query($conn , $sql)) {
        $Success = "User has been Updated Successfully!";
        header("Location: Updating_U.php?Success=".urlencode($Success));
        exit();
    }   
}
?>
```

Also, you should be doing validation before executing the query.

Comment: Oh thanks for that typeo i did not see it The Database does not look like there are any null values the boxes are unchecked